# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9fh6ocjf/scikit-image

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hopefully this does not count as a duplicate question. I have literally tried every option given in the answers of other posts and I have made no progress. 
I am currently running Arch Linux (if that matters) and I am trying to install pylab using `pip2 install pylab`
When looking at the Error Message, I see ImportError: No module named 'scipy'

`sudo pip2 install scipy` leads to

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize... [some stuff] ... failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-utk50pe0/scipy
```

I have tried `sudo pip2 install --upgradetools` only to be told that it is already installed.

I have tried `sudo pip2 install --upgrade pip`

I have tried all these with both pip and pip2 and with and without sudo for python 2.7 and 3.5. I am very lost and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to provide some more details on the error you are getting? FWIW I think scipy should be among the Arch Linux packages and matplotlib (which provides pylab) as well, so try installing these packages with pacman rather than pip.

Comment: I've tried sudo pacman -S numpy, scipty, matplotlib, and all the other dependencies, they all now just say no packpages were upgraded so I assume they're installed. However I cannot seem to import pylab or matplotlib. If I try pip2 install matplotlib, I get the same error as above.
If I try pip2 install pylab, I get:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip=build-BIgdY3/scikit-image.`

I am getting really desperate, but thanks for trying.